# MySQL Count name greater than a value

Tags: mysql

Please how can i check if a particular name is greater than a value in MySQL database. I want to do something like.
    SELECT id FROM table WHERE COUNT(name = 'john') > 2
i know this does not work, but i really need to do something like this.

An Example: A student studying CS, From New York, and grad point is 4.5 wants to check into a hostel.
I have a hostel tables with fields course, state, and Grade_Point. i want to select the hostel_id where no same user with the same course > 2, state > 2 and grade_point > 2 are in the same room.

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: Note that you don't need to do a SELECT first. In fact, it would be slightly counter-productive to do so. Also, the solutions below are focusing too much on the '2' as opposed to the simpler logic of 'more than 1'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `HAVING` clause :

```
SELECT t.id FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(t.name = 'john') > 2
```

MySQL takes boolean expression as `0,1` , so `SUM(t.name = 'john')` will sum the number of occurences john appears for each `ID` , and will bring back those that appear **more** then twice.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `id` is not unique and you want ids where `'john'` appears 3 or more times:

```
select id
from t
where name = 'john'
group by id
having count(*) > 2;
```

This should be more efficient than any version that uses conditional aggregation because it reduces the size of the data before doing the aggregation.

Comment: When I use `having` in my query, then should I also use `group by`? In other word why did you use `group by` in your query? That's because of `having` or `count(*)` ?

Comment: I used `group by` because I think the OP wants to count the number of times that `'john'` appears for each `id`.  Admittedly, this is rather speculative, for this question.  In general, you use `having` only with a `group by`.  MySQL extends the use of `having` for non-aggregated queries, as a way of using column aliases for filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;)

```
SELECT id FROM table HAVING COUNT(IF(name = 'john', 1, null)) > 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT name, count(*) 
 FROM YourTable 
 where name = 'john'
 GROUP BY  name
 HAVING count(*) > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Consiedr the following...

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY id;
+----+------+
| Id | Name |
+----+------+
|  1 | Q    |
|  2 | W    |
|  3 | E    |
|  4 | R    |
|  5 | T    |
|  6 | Y    |
+----+------+

INSERT INTO my_table (name) SELECT 'Q' FROM (SELECT 1) x LEFT JOIN my_table y ON y.name = 'Q' WHERE y.id IS NULL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY id;
+----+------+
| Id | Name |
+----+------+
|  1 | Q    |
|  2 | W    |
|  3 | E    |
|  4 | R    |
|  5 | T    |
|  6 | Y    |
+----+------+

INSERT INTO my_table (name) SELECT 'Z' FROM (SELECT 1) x LEFT JOIN my_table y ON y.name = 'Z' WHERE y.id IS NULL;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY id;
+----+------+
| Id | Name |
+----+------+
|  1 | Q    |
|  2 | W    |
|  3 | E    |
|  4 | R    |
|  5 | T    |
|  6 | Y    |
|  7 | Z    |
+----+------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Alternatively, you can just issue a simple INSERT on a UNIQUE column. And use the 'rows affected' as evidence of whether the name already exists.